# In Macroable.php line 96: Method body does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fairy new to Laravel. I have created a migration file named: create_notes_table and when running command php artisan migrate this error message pops up.

my create_notes_table file content

```
class CreateNotesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->number('card_id');
            $table->body('string');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }



    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('notes');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message states there is no `body()` method in migrations.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#columns

Change your `function up()` to :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('card_id');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

While we're at it, `number()` also doesn't exist, changed it to `integer()`
Edit: changed `number` to `integer`

Comment: table->number('card_id'); it should be integer

Answer (score 2):

While method "body" doesn't exist, instead it try this. To know for sureI it shoud be in the DB

```
// Use the string() method
$table->string('body');
```